# Place of the phrase

Tags: placement

> The "No Disc Inserted" error  appeared on the screen.

> The error "No Disc Inserted"  appeared on the screen.

Where should I use the phrase before “error” or after “error”?Especially while speaking which pne would be better?

Comment: I voted to leave it open because I believe I've given a fact-based non-opinion answer

Answer (score 3):

If it's an error that the person you're talking to is likely familiar with, then *'The "No Disc Inserted" error appeared on the screen*' is better. This grammar suggests the error is common enough that it has a name.

If it's some obscure error the person you're talking to is probably unfamiliar with, use '*The error "Spline Reticulation Failed" appeared on the screen*' is better. This grammar suggests the error is not common, so the speaker gives the words to describe it, rather than its name.

In this case, "No Disc Inserted" is a pretty common error, so you can go with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Following the **Mention Important Stuff Earlier**, I would use:

> The (or A) "No Disc Inserted" error appeared on the screen.

Comment: Unless of course the fact of the error is more important than the type. I would be fine with either option.

Answer (score 0):

Either is perfectly acceptable and grammatically valid. The meaning is essentially the same. There could be a difference of emphasis, but it would be a matter of context and opinion which order was preferable.